# Replace summary/description with another field in Views RSS output

Tags: 7, views, entities, feeds

I have a view for an RSS feed which uses the node output (only option it seems when RSS style is selected) so I cant choose custom fields. But, as the body field is 'text and summary' the RSS view uses that summary for the 'description' field but I'd like to use another field for that element in the feed.

Does that make sense?

An option is to just create another field-based view and my own templates to create an RSS output, but it just seems like such a trivial change to require so much work.

Would love to hear some thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The edit you added could be an answer; I would put it in an answer.

Comment: You can add fields through the settings, but last time I looked at it you couldn't change some of the predefined settings for example author or publish date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked it out. On the 'Manage Display' tab for a content type, there is a 'Custom Display Settings' section at the bottom. Opening that and selecting RSS gives you an RSS Display Fields area where you can change the fields to be used. Looks like it might just work for me.

Comment: I have searched deep and found servals solutions for D7 with template files,but this is obviously a better solution !

Answer (score 2):

Before rolling your own templates, you may be able to do what you want using the [Views RSS module](http://drupal.org/project/views_rss). This allows you to map fields to RSS elements, rather than being forced to use the node display.

Comment: Argh, looks great but no D7 release. :)

Comment: D'oh! That's too bad. Hopefully soon.

Comment: There is a RC now.